Deleting answer deletes... post? question? answer?
Here, the user intends to delete (just) his answer.



but is shocked as it turns out the "Delete" button shown actually refers to the entire "post" (which presumably means "question").
Or maybe "post" refers to just the answer, after all.

Both "questions" and "answers" are known as "posts". One is a post of type "question", the other is a post of type "answer"
In this case, the post being referred to is the answer just above the "delete" link.
